# setting tint color for selected tab in UITabBar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar

In Xcode 5 Dev Preview 2, I was able to execute the following:

`[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` //the color of the selected image and text (white)

In Xcode 5 Dev Preview 3, the same line of code throws an exception (see below).  The exception indicates that I may want to use '`barTintColor`' - but I do not - as this is the color of the overall UITabBar.  How can I set the color of the selected image and text in a UITabBar?

The new exception in Xcode 5 Dev Preview 3:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-setTintColor: is not allowed for use with the appearance proxy. Perhaps you want to use the barTintColor property.'
```

Thank you

Comment: In which iOS version you got this exception ?

Comment: would you like to try images in tabbar...

Answer (score 18):

I'm not seeing this with the latest Xcode 5 (5.0.2), but I do know that you want to call different methods to set the selected image tint color depending on whether you're running on iOS 6 or 7. Here's some sample code from one of my apps:

```
if ([RFSUtilities isIOS7OrHigher])
{
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
else
{
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

The `+[RFSUtilities isIOS7OrHigher]` just checks to see whether we're running on iOS 7 or above with [the proper version check](http://roadfiresoftware.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-check-the-ios-version-in-an-app/):

```
+ (BOOL)isIOS7OrHigher
{
    float versionNumber = floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber);
    return versionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Just add `tintColor` with color type in User Defined Runtime Attribute of the `UITabBar` class.

Still looking for the similar approach for inactive tabs... Anyone know?

[image]